# Publishing ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer on ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, performance

Please suggest some URL or steps to publish ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer service on ArcGIS 10.1 server so I can add in my application.

What are the best practice to do that to increase performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This location on the esri website has the steps to [publish](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgisonline/index.html#//010q000000v5000000).
and the [best practices](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgisonline/index.html#/Best_practices_for_hosted_tiled_map_services/010q00000081000000/).
This [online training class](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=search.results&searchterm=tile) has information about creating map packages.
Utah dot gov created their own [tiled map service](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/layers_ags_tiled.html).
There are several ways to accomplish this. It should be on the websites referenced.
[image: tilingscheme]

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply I will implement and let you know.

Comment: Can we publish ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer services on the local server?

Comment: I have followed the step to publish the service but the Map is showing blank. I don't know the reason behind it and it is not showing sharing tab when I publish SD File

Comment: sorry @Gunner I don't know what you've published, (vector/raster) how you published (dynamic/cached), how you are trying to view it, What data you are trying to view it with, or what coordinate system the base or any data are in.  you must edit you question or post another question to make things clear.

Comment: I have cached the service .I am using 102100(GCS 83) then reprojected to 4326(WGS 84).I am using vector data. I have done the step which you posted in answer.I know I am missing small thing.In the example they haven't use WGS 84.